# {newunicodechar} + \chapter{} produces two font-related warnings

Tags: fonts, unicode, scrbook, newunicodechar

I get 2 warnings when I compile the MWE. The warnings are:

Warning 1:
`` ./cuba.tex:13: Font shape `EU1/EversonMono(0)/bx/n' undefined(Font) using `EU1/EversonMono(0)/m/n' instead on input line 13.Font shape `EU1/EversonMono(0)/bx/n' undefined(Font) using `EU1/EversonMono(0)/m/n' instead ``

Warning 2: 
`./cuba.tex:0: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.`

My question is:
How do I solve the warnings?

Information:

1. I am using the `{scrbook}` document class and compiling using XeLaTeX.
2. The character "`⸱`" is "Word Separator Middle Dot". Its Unicode is U+2E31.
3. The Everson Mono font can be downloaded from: http://www.evertype.com/emono/

It has the regular (Everson Mono), **bold** (Everson Mono Bold), *italic* (Everson Mono Oblique), and ***bold italic*** (Everson Mono Bold Oblique).

4. The MWE:

   ```
   \documentclass{scrbook}

   \usepackage{fontspec}

   \usepackage{newunicodechar}
   \newfontface{\emr}{Everson Mono}% emr -- Everson Mono (regular)
   \newunicodechar{⸱}{\emr{⸱}}

   \newcommand{\titik}{\emr{⸱}}

   \begin{document}

   \chapter{Manusia (ma{\titik}nu{\titik}sia)}

   Manusia (ma{\titik}nu{\titik}sia).

   \end{document}
   ```
5. I use the `\newcommand` to make the MWE easier to read (for me at least) and also I will be using this Unicode often in the original document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\newfontface` you don't define a command that changes fonts respecting the current conditions. You *may* want that the `\titik` symbol doesn't respect a bold face condition, but the main problem is how you define it. It should be

```
\newfontface{\emr}{Everson Mono}% emr -- Everson Mono (regular)
\newunicodechar{⸱}{{\normalfont\emr ⸱}}

\newcommand{\titik}{⸱}
```

What you did selects the `\emr` font for the rest of the section title (or until the current group ends.

If you want that `\titik` respects bold face or italic declarations, use

```
\newfontfamily{\emr}{Everson Mono}% emr -- Everson Mono (regular)
\newunicodechar{⸱}{{\emr ⸱}}

\newcommand{\titik}{⸱}
```

---

What's the difference between `\newfontfamily` and `\newfontface`? The former command will set up a complete font family (based on the font name and the available shapes or based on the directive the user adds manually). The latter defines a “fixed” font, which can only change size.

Thus with `\newfontface{\emr}{Everson Mono}` you just define `\emr` to choose the regular version of the font, independently of the context, but you will get warnings about not defined font shapes (what you experienced). To the contrary, if you use `\newfontfamily` and issue `\emr` in a context where boldface is active, you will get Everson Mono Bold.

In both cases, `\emr` is a *declaration* that tells TeX to use the font until the current group ends. So if you want to use `\titik` with your definition, you need to add braces around it to limit the scope.

The defined command is similar to `\itshape` or `\bfseries`, which are not commands with an argument.

If you want to define a command with argument, after defining the font family or face named `\emr`, you can do

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textemr}{\emr}
```

and after this `\textemr{text}` will typeset `text` in Everson Mono.

Comment: I think I can sort of understand what you are explaining though with much difficulty as I don't know what `\newfontface` and `\newfontfamily` are or what they do, also what I did wrong (although I can see _where_ I went wrong). I'll try to read up about them. Thank you for the super fast help! <3